# decrypt a file in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cryptography

I am trying to decrypt the file which is saved in file system. And I again saving the decrypted (raw private key) to file system. Here is the code

```
        String decryptKey = "b6481a9253b76bd1629cbdf69a019aca23575caf1b78316c1dc257b8d4ba7e55";
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
        byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(decryptKey.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(this.getFilesDir() + "/decrypted");

        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(digestOfPassword, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);


        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fileInputStreams, cipher);//fis
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while ((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
            fos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
```

but I don't want to save the decrypted file to the device file system instead want to turn the input stream into a private key object. How to achieve this?

Comment: Instead of a `FileOutputStream` write the results to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: thank you.. worked